# CreateWindow coordinates are limited to 32767?

Tags: createwindow

How I can create child window with coordinates that are larger than 32767? For example:

```
HWND tmp = 
CreateWindow(
    _T( "BUTTON" ), _T( "Test" ),
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
    10, 45000, 80, 25,
    hWnd, (HMENU)1, (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle( NULL ), NULL );
```

This code creates button with coordinates 10;32767. Using of MoveWindow or SetWindowPos functions give same result.

I need to create window with scroll and child controls on it (simple form).

Comment: It would appear as though that is a windows limit, just tried to put a button in Delphi at left=50000 and in immediatly reduced it to 32767.  You might need to rethink your layout so that you dont need such a large scroll width.

Comment: Currently I'm fixing bug in very old project and it is not possible to do any refactoring. Btw, if I scroll window to a bottom and use MoveWindow - controls are moving correctry and they are stayed in correct coordinates after returning scroll (much more then 32767). Currently I'm implementing workaround - window manager that hooks scroll and focus events, but I don't want such ugly solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HWND CreateWindowExPatched( DWORD exStyle, LPCTSTR className, LPCTSTR title, DWORD style, int x, int y, int width, int height, HWND parent, HMENU menu, HINSTANCE instance, LPVOID param )
{
    HWND hWnd = NULL;

    ScrollWindow( parent, -x, -y, NULL, NULL );
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx( exStyle, className, title, style, 0, 0, width, height, parent, menu, instance, param );
    ScrollWindow( parent, x, y, NULL, NULL );

    return hWnd;
}

HWND CreateWindowPatched( LPCTSTR className, LPCTSTR title, DWORD style, int x, int y, int width, int height, HWND parent, HMENU menu, HINSTANCE instance, LPVOID param )
{
    return CreateWindowExPatched( 0, className, title, style, x, y, width, height, parent, menu, instance, param );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system are you using to run your code?

On my project, while Windows 7 seems to truncate coordinates to 16 bit signed integer range (-32768 and 32767), Window XP doesn't seem to do that and allows positioning from -2147483648 to 2147483647, the whole 32 bit signed integer range.

Comment: Both Windows XP / Windows 7